# When we are proving why ARIMA(0,1,1) is equal to simple exponential smoothing, why can we considered theta to be equal to (1-alpha)

Tags: self-study, arima, exponential-smoothing

I know this is a very basic question, but its not clarified within my lectures. 
Essentially when you have ARIMA(0,1,1)
You can simplify the theta 1 term in order to obtain SES via stating its (1-alpha), but why would the theta 1 term be considered 1 - alpha.

Comment: Have you worked through the math to convert the expression for an ARIMA(0,1,1) model to an exponential smoothing model?  It's just rearranging terms.  If you do so, it will become clear.

Comment: I've worked through the math, but I wondered if there was any logic as to behind why we let alpha equate 1-theta, like any theoretical logic, or it just math?

Comment: It's just math, really.